# digital audio output - what format is it in?

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio

My MacBook has an optical digital audio output 3.5 mm plug (see [here](http://www.larryjordan.biz/theres-a-fiber-option-connection-built-into-every-mac/)). I'm asking here on SO because I think this is a standard digital audio output plug; the description says I should use a Toslink cable with a Toslink mini-plug adapter or a fiber-optic cable.

I was wondering: What is the format of the audio data transferred over this cable? Is it a fixed format, e.g. 44.1kHz, 16bit integer, two-channel ([standard PCM like from an audio CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Disc_Digital_Audio))? Or what formats does it allow? For example, I would like to send 96kHz (or 48kHz), 32bit float (or 24bit integer), two-channel (or 6 channels) audio data over it. How is the data encoded? How does the receiver (the DA converter) know about the format? Is there some communication back from the receiver so that the receiver tells my computer what format it would prefer? Or how do I know the maximal sample rate and the maximal bit width of a sample?

How do I do that on the software side? Is it enough to tell CoreAudio to use whatever format I like and it puts that unmodified onto the cable? At least that is my goal. So basically my main questions are: What formats are supported, how do I know that my raw audio data in my application gets exactly in that format on the cable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digital audio interconnects like TOSLINK use the [S/PDIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/PDIF) protocol. The channel layout and compression status is encoded in the stream, and the sample rate is implied by the speed at which the signal is sent (!). For uncompressed streams, S/PDIF transmits 24-bit (integer) PCM data. (Lower bit depths can be transmitted as well; S/PDIF just pads them out to 24 bits anyway.) Note that, due to bandwidth constraints, compression must be used if more than two channels are being transmitted.

From the software side, on OS X, most of the properties of a digital audio output are controlled by the settings of your audio output device.

Comment: That mostly explains all my hardware-site questions! Thanks! Do you know what sample rates the digital output of my MacBookPro soundcard supports? I'm not sure if I can trust CoreAudio when it tells me that it supports whatever format, that it does not internally resamples/converts it. Can I? So if I pass in 24bit integer PCM data at 48kHz, it will just write that as-is on the cable? (In case no mixing with sound by other software occurs.)

Comment: All of Apple's recent hardware supports native sample rates up to 96 kHz. (My current MBA supports 44.1, 48, 88.2, and 96 kHz, for instance.)